# How to get the processor number on linux

Tags: linux

I need to get the processor number in my program with C/C++ language. My code 
like as follow:

```
 #include <unistd.h>
 int main()
 {
    int processorNum = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF);
    return 0;
 }
```

when i compile it , it had two errors:

```
error: '_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF' was not declared in this scope
error: 'sysconf' was not declared in this scope
```

so ,what should i do.

ps: my complier's version is gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1).should i link a library  file

**ps: Hi all, excuse me ,i made some mistakes. i forgot the head file.**

Comment: Quite strange, does not happen with my gcc. What was your compiler invocation?

Comment: No errors on my system - and `printf()`s correct number of processors when told to do so.

Comment: What OS are you compiling under ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1、The most  reliable way is to read `/proc/cpuinfo` file.  like `grep processor proc/cpuinfo`

2、use command `lscpu`